# Empty string detection in my Python?

Tags: python, string

This blows my mind. What am I missing?

I am trying to detect if a cell in an Excel sheet is empty or not. But none of the tests seem to work in the way I expect. I would expect that the simple "not idkt" test would detect both empty strings and None, but no... In fact, it seems like None is not detected by - well - any of the tests, because in the third row, that's what is getting printed.

Code:

```
def getFromExcelSheet():
    wb = load_workbook("input.xlsx")
    idkts = [];
    idktRows = get_worksheet_as_list(wb.get_sheet_by_name('Inputs'))
    # print "Got these idkts" 
    for row in idktRows:
        # print row[0]
        idkt = str(row[2]).strip()
        filename = str(row[3]).strip()
        if idkt == None:
            print "Idkt == none"

        if idkt is None:
            print "Idkt is none"

        if idkt == u"":
            print "Idkt is ''"

        if idkt != u"":
            print "Idkt is !=''"

        if not idkt:
            print "not IDKT"

        if idkt:
            print "idkt"

        print idkt
```

Output

```
Idkt is !=''
idkt
3398041577

Idkt is !=''
idkt
3498100937

Idkt is !=''
idkt
None
```

Comment: What does it say if you `print repr(idkt)` on the last line?

Comment: '3398041577', '3498100937', None'

Comment: if the None has `'` around it, it is a string (and not the `None` constant...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`idkt` isn't empty, it's a string containing the word `'None'`.
Here's your issue:

```
idkt = str(row[2]).strip()
```

`row[2]` is a `None`, which becomes `'None'` when you call `str` on it.
Try this:

```
if idkt == 'None': print 'yay!'
```

You'd be better off testing for emptiness *before* the string conversion:

```
idkt = str(row[2]).strip() if row[2] else None
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're converting the cells to strings, and then comparing the result to the Python's `None` (which is not a string).

I assume you're using [openpyxl](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/tutorial.html) in which case you should access the value of the cell via `.value`, e.g.

```
idkt = row[2].value
```

You will then have a standard Python object (`str`/`int`/`None` etc) that represents that data within the cell. You should use this value for your non-empty check, and it will behave the way you originally expected:

```
if idkt not in ('', None):  # remember bool(0) == False
    ...
```